# Does Clang's assembler support the "u" suffix for integer literals?

Tags: assembly, arm, clang

[system/startup_mcore.S:374:22: expected')' 8466.word (0x43B90000u) 8467](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spQ4H.png)
When I'm using Clang-14.0.0 to compile an arm64 asm file,it gives the above errors.
When I've deleted the "u" suffix, the errors disappered and the compiling passed.
ChatGPT says that : The integer suffixes "u" and "U" indicate an unsigned integer type. Clang does not support the "u" suffix for integer literals.
and the link given is [text](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#integer-suffixes)
However, it takes a lot time and the words above haven't been found yet.(sad~~)

I'm expecting that is there any offcial documentation that defines this rule?

Comment: Please replace the picture of an error message with an error message as text as per policy.  Will then take back my downvote.

Comment: Thx for your advice. And the replacement has been made.

Comment: That's not a particularly good replacement...  Ideally put the whole text in the image into a preformatted block (like with source code) and then remove the link entirely.

Comment: Just to clarify fuz's answer: clang is primarily a compiler for C, C++ and related languages, so usually when people talk about whether clang "supports" something, they are talking about whether it does so when compiling one of those languages.  And of course it does support `u` for C/C++/etc; it is a very basic requirement of those languages.  Claiming otherwise would be nonsense.  But clang also contains an assembler, which is what you are using, and so all bets are off since assembly is an entirely different language.

Comment: clang doesn't really document its assembler syntax, but it is mostly compatible with the GNU assembler gas, so the [gas manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) is a good resource when wondering about features.  In particular, the gas manual does precisely define a [syntax for integer literals](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Integers.html), and you will note that `u` is not mentioned.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: Seem like posting images would be a protest move against AI companies scraping open source code and creating generative AI code engines based on such code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integer size suffixes `U`, `L`, `UL`, `ULL`, `LL`, and so on are supported for the C, C++, and Objective C languages as per the respective language specifications.  They are not supported for assembly source files and do not make sense there.

Also I recommend not to trust AI assistants too much.  Especially for niche topics they are likely to just hallucinate things.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'm changing the compiling tools from gcc to clang. And I'll revise other MACRO definition.

Comment: I would argue against, **do not make sense there**.  It is certainly valuable to able to share sources of truth in included files for constant values shared between C/C++ and assembler.  clang--, gcc++.

Comment: @artlessnoise The suffix doesn't make sense because assembly sources never derive types from integer literals.  What determines the type is the directive or instruction used.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.  The assembler can ignore it to support compatibility with constants shared with 'C'.  The ability to inter-operate between languages is what I was saying makes  **'does not make sense** incorrect.  Something might not be a design goal, but that by itself doesn't make something useless as there can be other design goals.